# Kafka consumer group not rebalancing when increasing partitions

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a situation where in my dev environment, my Kafka consumer groups will rebalance and distribute partitions to consumer instances just fine after increasing the partition count of a subscribed topic.

However, when we deploy our product into its kubernetes environment, we aren't seeing the consumer groups rebalance after increasing the partition count of the topic. Kafka recognized the increase which can be seen from the server logs or describing the topic from the command line. However, the consumer groups won't rebalance and recognize the new partitions. From my local testing, kafka respects metadata.max.age.ms (default 5 mins). But in kubernetes the group never rebalances.

I don't know if it affects anything but we're using static membership.

The consumers are written in Java and use the standard Kafka Java library. No messages are flowing through Kafka, and adding messages doesn't help. I don't see anything special in the server or consumer configurations that differs from my dev environment. Is anyone aware of any configurations that may affect this behavior?

** Update **

The issue was only occurring for a new topic. At first, the consumer application was starting before the producer application (which is intended to create the topic). So the consumer was auto creating the topic. In this scenario, the topic defaulted to 1 partition. When the producer application started it, updated the partition count per configuration. After that update, we never saw a rebalance.

Next we tried disabling consumer auto topic creation to address this. This prevented the consumer application from auto creating the topic on subscription. Yet still after the topic was created by the producer app, the consumer group was never rebalanced, so the consumer application would sit idle.

According to the documentation I've found, and testing in my dev environment, both of these situations *should* trigger a rebalance. For whatever reason we don't see that happen in our deployments. My temporary workaround was just to ensure that the topic is already created prior to allowing my consumer's to subscribe. I don't like it, but it works for now. I suspect that the different behavior I'm seeing is due to my dev environment running a single kafka broker vs the kubernetes deployments with a cluster, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka defaults to update topic metadata only after 5 minutes, so will not detect partition changes immediately, as you've noticed. The deployment method of your app shouldn't matter, as long as network requests are properly reaching the broker.

Plus, check your partition assignment strategy to see if it's using sticky assignment. This will depend on what version of the client you're using, as the defaults changed around 2.7, I think

> No messages are flowing through Kafka

If there's no data on the new partitions, there's no real need to rebalance to consume from them

Comment: We're utilizing the newer cooperative sticky assignment strategy by default in our application. This is both in my dev environment and when deployed. We've also tried sending messages through, but the rebalance isn't happening. Our test team actually noticed this because messages weren't getting processed. This is when I noticed that those messages were going into the new partitions, but as there was no rebalance they weren't getting read.

Comment: Do you have `auto.offset.reset=latest`? If so, then nothing will be processed for existing data

Comment: It's set to earliest. This is exclusively a rebalance issue. We can force a rebalance by shutting down the consumer application and letting the sessions expire (since we're using static membership), the restarting it. Once a rebalance occurs the new partitions are distributed correctly and messages flow. The problem is simply that a rebalance isn't occuring after increasing partitions. It should occur after metadata.max.age.ms.

Comment: If you restart the consumer process, then does a rebalance happen? I personally have always done that after increasing partitions, anyway, as we didn't want to wait for the metadata refresh.

Comment: Yeah, but as we're using static membership I need to kill the consumer until the session times out.